# Problems using Tesseract-OCR on Python

Tags: python, anaconda, tesseract

I'm new in programming and I'm trying to use Tesseract OCR to read the text of an image, but I can't make it work! I installed tesseract_OCR, pytesseract and pillow in my environment. Does anyone have a tip?

Input:

```
from PIL import Image 

import pytesseract

print( pytesseract.image_to_string( Image.open('phrase.jpg') ) )
```

Output:

```
 C:\Anaconda2\envs\ambiente36\python.exe 

 C:/Users/Simone/Desktop/curso_programacao/Ler_imagens/ler_imagens

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\ambiente36\lib\site- 
packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 194, in run_and_get_output
run_tesseract(**kwargs)

File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\ambiente36\lib\site- 
packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 165, in run_tesseract
proc = subprocess.Popen(command, **subprocess_args())

File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\ambiente36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
restore_signals, start_new_session)

File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\ambiente36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in 
_execute_child 
startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo 
especificado

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Simone/Desktop/curso_programacao/Ler_imagens/ler_imagens", 
line 6, in <module>
phrase = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('phrase.jpg'))

File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\ambiente36\lib\site- 
packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 286, in image_to_string
return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)

File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\ambiente36\lib\site- 
packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 201, in run_and_get_output
raise TesseractNotFoundError()

pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed 
or it's not in your path
```

Comment: is your image file in the same folder as your script?

Comment: yes, it is in the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Steps you should follow to configure tessaract in your environment
here are the steps you should follow

first install python and pip [here](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nfldb/wiki/Python-&-pip-Windows-installation) are steps 
then install pillow, pytesseract as [here](https://www.manejandodatos.es/2013/10/installing-new-modules-python/)

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser.pytesser import *

image_file = "FULL/PATH/TO/YOUR/IMAGE/image.png"
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print "=====output=======\n"
print text
```

link for [download](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/downloads/detail?name=pytesser_v0.0.1.zip&can=2&q=) pytessaract 
you can find a complete example [here](https://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/)

Comment: the OP seems to use python 3

Comment: So it means that I can't use anaconda environment for Tesseract-OCR, I need to create a new environment by installing python and pip?

Comment: if you have installed anaconda python correctly you dont need to install PIL.. you just have to run the above example

Comment: if you have installed python-anaconda then download below zip and extract it to the same directory where the above code is in then run the example
https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/downloads/detail?name=pytesser_v0.0.1.zip&can=2&q=

Answer (score 1):

It seems like either Tesseract is not installed correctly or the path to tesseract does not point where tesseract was actually installed.

> pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not
>   installed  or it's not in your path

I suggest that you check your installations first by following [the official documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki).

I've recently written a pretty simple guide to Tesseract but it should enable you to write your first OCR script and clear up some hurdles that I experienced when things were less clear than I would have liked in the documentation.

In case you'd like to check them out, here I'm sharing the links with you:

- [Getting started with Tesseract - Part I: Introduction](https://medium.com/@bkaankuguoglu/getting-started-with-tesseract-part-i-2a6a6b1cf75e)
- [Getting started with Tesseract - Part II: Image Pre-processing](https://medium.com/@bkaankuguoglu/getting-started-with-tesseract-part-ii-f7f9a0899b3f)

Answer (score 1):

You need to install tesseract using windows installer available [here](https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki). Then you should install the python wrapper as:

```
pip install pytesseract
```

Then you should also set the tesseract path in your script after importing pytesseract library as below (Please do not forget that installation path might be modified in your case!):

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
```

Note: It is tested on Anaconda3 without any issues.